# My text wont center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my text. I have tried the align tag and it will not center. Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

Here is what I'm trying to center:

```
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong><em> </em></strong></span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong><em>Welcome to Ian&#8217;s Driving Academy</em></strong></span></h1>

<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Call  07931  104302</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong><span style="color: #000000;">or    01226  715186</span></strong></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> iansdrivingacademy@gmail.com</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Hi my name is Ian of Ian&#8217;s Driving Academy which is based in cudworth</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">I am a fully qualified Grade 5 Driving Instructor (ADI)<br />
I am patient friendly and calm understanding all your needs.</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong><a href="../wp-content/uploads/2010/08/DSALogo.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-141" title="DSALogo" src="http://imgur.com/qllCZSt.png" alt="" width="242" height="108" /></a></strong></span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong><span style="color: #000000;"> Approved and registered with the</span></strong></span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> <strong> Driving Standards Agency.</strong></span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">I have been trained and worked for one of the biggest driving school in Great Britain</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"> </span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">My Ambition</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">I now want to bring driving in to the 21st century by offering top quality training with a patient and friendly atmosphere   (my high pass rate helps) and making sure that my pupils are getting the best use of time and enjoying the total learning experience</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Lessons</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">ll my lessons are personalised to the pupils requirements from the nervous beginners ,to pupils suffering Adhd even mild brain trauma. to the experienced driver who just wants a refresher coarse.</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Block booking discounts are available</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Learning to drive</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">The practical test requires a wide knowledge of driving on all kinds of roads, and in varied conditions. You will be expected to perform a manoeuvre,independent drive,and possibly an emergency stop. It is essential that you have professional tuition in order to get to the require standard. The average number of one hour lessons required to pass your test is approximately 45 and 20 private hours. You will be given a driver&#8217;s record which will keep you informed of your progress.</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Areas covered</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;"><strong>I cover </strong><strong>Barnsley</strong>, <strong>North Sheffield</strong>, parts of  <strong>Wakefield</strong><strong> </strong>.</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Training vehicle</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">The vehicle we used is a Toyota Yaris it gives all the comfort and luxuries you would expect from a top class Eco friendly training vehicle.</span></h4>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">Personal training</span></h1>
<h4 style="font-size:16px;">My tuition is kept to the highest standards by regular professional development courses as recommended by the Driving Standards Agency.</span></h4>
```

Comment: Where are you even specifying that you want to align your text?

Comment: One way would be to wrap that entire block in an enclosing `<div style="text-align:center;"> </div>`, but really, you've done just about everything wrong here.

Comment: I see nothing in your code that's trying to align anything. On a side note; why are you using inline styles when a proper stylesheet would better serve your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

You really should look into separating you HTML and your styling. However if you insist on using inline styling you will need to use the below HTML.

```
<div align="center">
 <h4 style="font-size:16px;"></h1>
</div>
```

NB

You should really think about learning some of the basics before you venture into writing your own page from scratch. Look into using a WYSIWYG until you really know what you are doing.

**Tips**

Your open tags should be the same as closing tags.

```
<H1></H1>
```

You can't have just closing tags with out opening

**No**

```
</span>
```

**Yes**

```
<span> </span>
```

Comment: `align="center"` is outdated and in past used with tables

Comment: Did you read the code? Using depreciated HTML is the least of his worries.

Comment: probably because the rest of you HTML  is wrong. If i were you i would remove all the styling and then add it back in once you have the centering sorted.

Comment: see my answer for tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<h4 style="text-align: center;">hello</h4>
```